# Requests Attempting to grab cookie but get empty CookieJar

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple hours and no answers I've found on here or elsewhere has worked.  I am using requests version `2.26.0` and trying to grab the cookie to add to my headers for later use.  I did notice on the page that the cookie starts with php-session, perhaps there is a different way I need to grab it besides requests.  Anyways, here is the headers I am using and the code I used to try and get the cookie, all it ever outputs is `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`, no matter what I try.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "565",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Cookie": "ig_cb=1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Host": "www.numlookup.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.numlookup.com",
    "Referer": "https://www.numlookup.com",
    "Sec-GPC": "1",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"    
}

s = requests.Session()
s2 = s.get("https://www.numlookup.com/", headers=headers).cookies

print(s2)
```

Comment: Is that really sending any cookies? Have you checked it in browser?

Comment: Yes, I checked the network traffic on the page.  Upon request it assigns a cookie.

Comment: For me it isn't sending any cookies, Are you sign in user? But your code should work fine if it sends cookies!

Comment: No I am not signed in.  I am trying to re-create the post request that is sent once you type in a phone number to search.  Sending the request though will need the right headers and part of it is the cookie.

Comment: Okay! now I think I understand your problem. But that URL is not sending any cookie at least for me. What is cookies is it sending for you?

Comment: Well inspecting element, going to network and reloading the page the first one is a GET with file type "/" and if you open that part of the request headers is the cookie.  That is what I need.  It start with "php_session".  After this I will need to do the captcha and get that ID for that too but that's another story.